# using awk to find special charecters in txt file

Tags: bash, awk

I need to scan a file with many different special charecters and values.
Given a set of special charecters - I need to provide the value next to it:

```
547 %$ 
236 \"
4523 &* 
8876 (*
8756 "/
...
```

I am using an awk command with gsub in order to find the sequences as they are.

```
awk -v st="$match_string" 'BEGIN {gsub(/(\[|\]|\-|\$|\*|\:|\+|\"|\(|\))/,"\\\\&", st)} match($0,st) {print;exit}' file.txt
```

The command works great e.g.

```
> (*
>> 8876 (*
```

However I am having trouble using the command to locate the \" sequence
I am trying to add to the gsub different strings to represnt the sequence:

```
|\\|
|\\\\|
|\\\\"|
...
```

But the result is always:

```
> \"
>> 8756 "/
```

It seems that the gsub does not work, and the \" is interpeted just as "
Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why don't you juse use `grep '\\"' file` ?

Comment: If you want to use fixed strings instead of regexes, maybe use `index()` instead?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the index() ? give an example...

Comment: I am actually using awk because I have places where I am looking for multiple lines starting with a begin pattern and ending with an end pattern. As far as I know, it can't be done with grep